# Multiple require & permit strong parameters rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, strong-parameters

In the below case, i am trying to use strong parameters. I want to require `email_address, password` and permit `remember_me` fields.

But using like below it only allows the **LAST line** in the method Ex:- In below case it only take `params.permit(:remember_me)`

```
  private

  def registration_params
    params.require(:email_address)
    params.require(:password)
    params.permit(:remember_me)
  end
```

Another Ex:- In this below case, if i rearrange it like below it will take only `params.require(:email_address)` where am i going wrong ?

```
  def registration_params
    params.require(:password)
    params.permit(:remember_me)
    params.require(:email_address)
  end
```

**UPDATE**
Params hash be like

```
{
              "utf8" => "✓",
     "email_address" => "test1@gmail.com",
          "password" => "password123",
       "remember_me" => "true",
            "commit" => "Log in",
        "controller" => "registration",
            "action" => "sign_in"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your registration form? It looks like you aren't setting the form up correctly to use strong parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok found the answer through a friend ...one way to do this is

```
params.require(:email_address)
params.require(:password)
params.permit(
:email_address,
:password,
:remember_me
)
```

Works good.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Here is the Rails way for you to handle logins and, I believe, cases where you need to 'require' multiple parameters and provide errors back to the user.

Unlike using strong params, this approach provides feedback to the user (using validation errors) when parameters are missing or blank. This is more user-friendly than throwing an exception.

1. Create an `ActiveModel` (*not* `ActiveRecord`) form backing object. This form backing object is where you specify which fields are required and when a call to `valid?` is performed, these fields will be validated.

   With this, you will get nice user-friendly errors if:

   - email is missing
   - password is missing
   - email and password do not match

   **models/session.rb**

   ```
   class Session
     include ActiveModel::Model

     attr_accessor :password, :email, :remember_me

     validates_presence_of :password, :email        # these fields are required!

     def authenticate
       return false unless valid?   # this checks that required params
                                    # are present and adds errors to the
                                    # errors object if not

       if User.authenticate(:password, :email)  # validate credentials
         true
       else              
         errors.add(:email, "and password didn't match")  # wrong credentials. add error!
         false
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Create the controller. Here is what your controller would look like for logging in a user:

   **app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

   ```
   class SessionsController < ApplicationController
     # GET /login
     def new
       @session = Session.new
     end

     # POST /login
     def create
       @session = Session.new(login_params)
       if @session.authenticate
         # do whatever you need to do to log the user in
         # set remember_me cookie, etc.
         redirect_to '/success', notice: 'You are logged in'
       else
         render :new   # shows the form again, filled-in and with errors
       end
     end

     private

     def login_params
       params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password, :remember_me)
     end
   end
   ```
3. Set up the view

   **app/views/sessions/new.html.erb**

   ```
   <% if @session.errors.any? %>
     <ul>
       <% @session.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
     </ul>
   <% end %>

   <%= form_for @session, :url => login_path do |f| %>
       <div>
         <%= f.label :email, 'Email:' %>
       </div>
       <div>
         <%= f.text_field :email %>
       </div>
       <div>
         <%= f.label :password, 'Password:' %>
       </div>
       <div>
         <%= f.password_field :password %>
       </div>
       <div>
         <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Remember Me?' %>
         <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
       </div>
       <div>
         <%= f.submit %>
       </div>
   <% end %>
   ```
4. Lastly, make sure the routes are configured

   **config/routes.rb**

   ```
   get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
   post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
   ```

Comment: i donnt think we can use multiple `require` like that ..anyway it says `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1))` if it try in your way

Comment: i tried ..now it says `NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "password123$":String)`

Comment: Doesn't look like strong params work like I thought :/ Sorry.  Could you post your params hash?

Comment: So upon further reading, this may not be the Rails Way to do what you're trying to do. Do you use the params you are trying to require for mass assignment? (ie, passing them to a .new, .create, .update call?). Or are you just looking up the user in the database?

Comment: In other words: are you signing in a user or registering them?

Answer (score 0):

Stong parameters are to prevent mass-assignment to Active Record models. Your parameters should be set up in a model backed form. Example from the [Michael Hartl Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up):

**REGISTRATION FORM**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This will create a parameter that looks like:

**PARAMS**

```
{
          "utf8" => "✓",
 "user" =>  { email: "test1@gmail.com", name:"Test Name", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password" },
   "remember_me" => "true",
        "commit" => "Log in",
    "controller" => "registration",
        "action" => "sign_in"
}
```

Then in your registration controller you can use strong parameters like:

**STRONG PARAMETERS**

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

It looks like in your case, you are handling a log in, in which case, you only need to use regular parameters to capture the login information.

**SESSION CREATION**

```
def sign_in
   email = params[:email]
   password = params[:password]
   if User.authenticate!(email, password)
     # do something
   else 
     # do something different
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

2020 solution:

```
def registration_params
  params.require([:email_address, :password])               #require all of these
  params.permit(:email_address, :password, :remember_me)    #return hash
end
```

Comment: This only works in Rails 5+.