# Ruby Strong Params: NoMethodError undefined method permit for Integer

Tags: ruby, strong-parameters

My controller:

```
class V1::SendContractController < V1::BaseController

  def create
    byebug
    bride_membership = Wedding.find(send_params[:weddingId]).bride_memberships[0]
    SendBrideContractJob.perform_now(bride_membership, send_params[:contractId])
    render json: { enqueuedDelivery: true }, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def send_params
    params
      .require(:weddingId)
      .permit(:contractId)
  end

end
```

My params

```
Parameters: {"weddingId"=>4, "contractId"=>20, "send_contract"=>{"weddingId"=>4, "contractId"=>20}}
```

The error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for 4:Integer):
```

But then when I `byebug` it I get what I want!

```
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"weddingId"=>4, "contractId"=>20, "controller"=>"v1/send_contract", "action"=>"create", "send_contract"=>{"weddingId"=>4, "contractId"=>20}} permitted: false>
(byebug) params[:weddingId]
4
```

And I'm using `axios` with an interceptor to take care of formatting issues:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if(config.url !== "/authentications") {
    config.paramsSerializer = params => {
      // Qs is already included in the Axios package
      return qs.stringify(params, {
        arrayFormat: "brackets",
        encode: false
      });
    };
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.state.token.token}`
    config.headers.common['Authorization']= `Bearer ${store.state.token.token}`
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/vnd.bella.v1+json'
    config.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/vnd.bella.v1+json'
    return config
  }
  return config
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that require gives you the object at the key you provide to do further permit and / or require calls.

Perhaps you could try (not tested):

```
params.require(:weddingId)
params.permit(:weddingId, :contractId)
```

Edit: there's this too: [Multiple require & permit strong parameters rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613499/multiple-require-permit-strong-parameters-rails-4)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424671/what-is-params-requireperson-permitname-age-doing-in-rails-4).The `require` ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns the parameter at the given key, otherwise raises an `ActionController::ParameterMissing error`.

```rb
p =  { "weddingId"=>4, "contractId"=>20 }

ActionController::Parameters.new(p).require(:weddingId)
# 4

p = { "weddingId"=>nil, "contractId"=>20 }

ActionController::Parameters.new(p).require(:weddingId)
# ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: weddingId
```

If you want to make sure `:weddingId` is present:

```rb
def contract_params
    params.require(:weddingId)
    params.permit(:contractId, :weddingId)
end
```

BTW, `SendContractController` is better called `ContractsController`.